# Debug Play 2 framework project in Eclipse?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I need help how to set up debugging for a Play 2.0.4 project in Eclipse. What do I have to configure for that? I already eclipsified my project and imported it into the Eclipse workspace. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 3):

First create a eclipse project with `play eclipse` or `play eclipse with-source=true`. Open that project in Eclipse

Start play with `play debug`. And the start the app with the `run` command. (or directly `play debug run`

Then connect eclipse via Remote-Debugging: Use the `Connect JPDA` with `Debug As` to start a debugging session. The debug port is 9999.

See also: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/IDE